# Нормально ли удалять комментарии о том, что всё работает под конкурирующими ответами?

Tags: обсуждение, ответы, правила, удаление-комментариев, спасибо

Вот [вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1174243/178988) с двумя ответами.

Один из них получил от автора вопроса комментарий

> Спасибо. Вот это работает.

а другой

> Эта конструкция почему-то не работает (Python 3.7)/(PyCharm 2020.2)

Из-за того, что в первом комментарии есть слово "спасибо", любой человек может удалить его одним голосом, что и произошло.

На мой взгляд, удаление подобных комментариев в принципе неправильно, поскольку в комментарии содержится полезная информация о том, что ответ действительно правильный. Ещё меньше мне нравится ситуация, когда такой комментарий удаляется автором конкурирующего ответа. И ещё меньше, когда под этим самым ответом написано, что он не подошёл.

Считаем ли мы по-прежнему, что это нормально и любые комментарии с благодарностями могут удаляться кем угодно?

Comment: Заметьте, даже если ответ подошел ТС, это не значит, что он *"правильный"*. Правильность, в некотором приближении, определяется голосами.

Comment: Как минимум то, что система позволяет автоматом удалить комментарий, которому меньше 4 часов, точно ненормально. Спасибо должно быть хотя бы прочитано.

Comment: Система, также, позволяет автоматом удалять спам, который флагнули 5 раз (емнип), это тоже ненормально, он тоже должен быть прочитан? )

Comment: @Kromster, 5 человек != 1 человек. И тем более 5 человек != 1 конкурент.

Comment: Вроде бы это я удалил "спасибу", так что это не "устранение конкурентов" :)

Comment: @dIm0n, ну я же вижу, кто удалил.

Comment: @Qwertiy не знал, извиняюсь тогда

Comment: "... когда такой комментарий удаляется автором конкурирующего ответа". Ничего себе тут оказывается страсти какие творятся :)

Comment: Для болле конструктивного обсуждения, надо удалившего спросить @VictorVosMottor Скажите пожалуйста, зачем вы комментарий удалили?

Answer (score 15):

> На мой взгляд, удаление подобных комментариев в принципе неправильно

Правильно.

Если ответ работает, то его нужно принимать и ставить галочку, а не комментарий писать.

Comment: Но заставить принять ответ нельзя (кстати, на тот момент принятого ответа не было). А ещё может быть несколько работающих ответов, а принять можно только один. А ещё подобный комментарий может быть написан не автором вопроса.

Comment: И я не понял, что значит слово "правильно" в твоём ответе - согласие со мной, или отрицание?

Comment: @Qwertiy отрицание)

Comment: @Qwertiy политика SO такая, что после получения ответа комментарии уже бесполезны и их нужно удалять.

Comment: @Qwertiy - "Вы со мной не согласны?" - "Согласен" - "Согласны с тем, что не согласны?" - "Не согласен".

Comment: @Suvitruf-AndreiApanasik смешные комментарии удалять нельзя.

Answer (score 6):

Инструменты надо использовать по назначению: молотки - для гвоздей, микроскопы - для наблюдений, галки - для принятия ответов, а комментарии для уточнений и комментирования .. и это хорошо, потому что остается всего 2 сущности - вопрос и ответ, и не надо продираться через комментарии для того чтобы выяснить что все не так или наоборот или так но не совсем и тд и тп. Это-то выгодно и отличает SO от форумов, где пока не прочтешь 8 страниц флуда, не поймешь как же быть.

Comment: Интересно, как понятность без комментариев применима к [соседнему ответу](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/10810/%d0%9d%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bc-%d1%87%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%81%d1%91-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%83%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%80%d1%83%d1%8e%d1%89%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b5#10811).

Comment: Интересно что вы имеете ввиду, но раз вы не говорите .. )

Comment: [Вроде очевидно, что это.](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/10810/%d0%9d%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bc-%d1%87%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%81%d1%91-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%83%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%80%d1%83%d1%8e%d1%89%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b5?noredirect=1#comment45851_10811)

Comment: Вот вы выяснили что ответ непонятен в комментариях - так внесите уточнения в ответ